# Add different sizes packaging boxes to orders plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

So im selling frozen items in special eps boxes in woocommerce, i need a plugin, i got 2 different sizes.
One small can contain 5 items and costs €1,5 and the other medium  15 items €2,5

If someone would order 16 items it should automaticly add 1x small 1x medium box to the bill

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a job for a plugin! I haven't used it personally, but it looks like [Auto Add Product to Cart](https://www.asanaplugins.com/product/auto-add-products-to-cart-woocommerce/) can do the job for you. From the description:

> You can use conditions like “cart subtotal”, “products in cart”,
> “categories in cart”, “money spent history”, “purchase history”,
> “quantity of products in cart”, “quantity of categories in cart”,
> “Roles”, “Customers”, “Number of orders” and etc.

Comment: I think i can make that work, thank you !